# Split a data set into two data sets based on x coordinates and y coordinates

Tags: r

I have data set of a large size, the data looks like the following:

```
         x_coord    y_coords             Y
   [1,] 0.8775213887 0.705373861  0.1281382382
   [2,] 0.7685332086 0.584642385  1.9679113354
   [3,] 0.2789631383 0.939768854  0.9075644917
   [4,] 0.5291636926 0.828879917  6.1022986770
   [5,] 0.9629070312 0.151365314 -0.4051817388
    :        :         :           :     
    :        :         :           : 
  [100,] 0.0345605961 0.672313672  0.4375736393
```

x and y coordinates between 0 an 1.

I want to split the data to two data set based on x coordinates and y coordinates.

For the first data set, I want to select the rows where x and y coordinates between 0.3 and 0.4. 
And the remaining data will be in second data set.

I tried to use "for loop" but I know it is good to not to use for loop because it is slow. 
Is there a package or another way without using the for loop. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `split` in combination with the function `between` from `dplyr` package that allow to test if a number is a specific interval.

This will return a list of two dataframes TRUE and FALSE corresponding to parts of the initial dataframe satisfying or not your interval:

```r
df <- data.frame(xcoord = seq(0,1,by = 0.01),
                 ycoord = seq(0,1,by = 0.01))

library(dplyr)
L <- split(df, between(df$xcoord, 0.3, 0.4) & between(df$ycoord, 0.3,0.4))

DF1 <- L["TRUE"] # Contain values satisfying the condition
DF2 <- L["FALSE"] # contain the remaining values (not satisfying the condition)
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try subsetting your matrix:

```
d1 <- mat[mat$x_coord >= 0.3 & mat$x_coord <= 0.4 &
          mat$y_coords >= 0.3 & mat$y_coords <= 0.4, ]
d2 <- mat[mat$x_coord < 0.3 | mat$x_coord > 0.4 |
          mat$y_coords < 0.3 | mat$y_coords > 0.4, ]
```

Comment: This matrix is inside list, I mean list[[i]] gives me the above matrix. Is that not problem. Thanks

Comment: You could use my logic above with `lapply`, depending on the exact output you want.